# exclude specific commands from saving into history

Tags: zsh, command-history

I want to exclude some specific commands from saving into zsh history.

for e.g: exclude mpv/mpc commands from saving into zsh history regardless of setting `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` or not.

I found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1371625/779670) but it does not work when I test it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a hook function to check the command before adding to the history file:

```
zshaddhistory() {
  case ${1%% *} in
    (mpv|mpc) return 1;;
  esac
  return 0;
}
```

Quoting the section of the man page (`man zshmisc`, under ["Hook Functions"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html)):

> If any of the hook functions returns status 1 (or any non-zero value other than 2, though this is not guaranteed for future versions of the shell) the history line will not be saved, although it lingers in the history until the next line is executed, allowing you to reuse or edit it immediately.
>
> If any of the hook functions returns status 2 the history line will be saved on the internal history list, but not written to the history file. In case of a conflict, the first non-zero status value is taken.

Comment: Well, where should I put this function to make it a hook?

Comment: @Niing I think that `~/.zshrc` would be a reasonable place.

Comment: I resolved this by externalizing the definition and importing it back into `~/.zshrc`, thank you.